# Returning an enum from a function in C?

Tags: c, function, enums

If I have something like the following in a header file, how do I declare a function that returns an enum of type Foo?

```
enum Foo
{
   BAR,
   BAZ
};
```

Can I just do something like the following?

```
Foo testFunc()
{
    return Foo.BAR;
}
```

Or do I need to use typedefs or pointers or something?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In C++, you could use just `Foo`.

In C, you must use `enum Foo` until you provide a typedef for it.

And then, when you refer to `BAR`, you do not use `Foo.BAR` but just `BAR`.  All enumeration constants share the same namespace (the “ordinary identifiers” namespace, used by functions, variables, etc).

Hence (for C):

```
enum Foo { BAR, BAZ };

enum Foo testFunc(void)
{
    return BAR;
}
```

Or, with a `typedef`:

```
typedef enum Foo { BAR, BAZ } Foo;

Foo testFunc(void)
{
    return BAR;
}
```

Comment: yet another reason why people dislike C++

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the individual values in the `enum` are identifiers in their own right, just use:

```
enum Foo testFunc(){
  return BAR;
}
```

Comment: In C, it needs enum Foo; in C++, just Foo would be OK.

Comment: Thanks. Or the type def that Kenny suggests, I suppose.

Comment: Yes - or the typedef would work, but in C++ that is 'automatic' but in C it must be created manually.

Answer (score 2):

I think some compilers may require

```
typedef enum tagFoo
{
  BAR,
  BAZ,
} Foo;
```

Comment: C compilers would accept the function with the typedef in place; C++ compilers do not require it.

Answer (score 2):

```
enum Foo
{
   BAR,
   BAZ
};
```

In C, the return type should have enum before it.  And when you use the individual enum values, you don't qualify them in any way.

```
enum Foo testFunc()
{
    enum Foo temp = BAR;
    temp = BAZ;
    return temp;
}
```