# c: inline enum with a function implementation

Tags: c, enums, inline

I have come across some c code where the there is an enum type followed by a function implementation, such as this:

```
enum OGHRet funcX ( OGH *info, void *data, int size )
{
    /* c code that does stuff here */
}
```

I am confused over how this enum statement works inline with the function implementation.
I assume it is the return type of funcX, but why is declared explicitly with enum?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its just saying its returning an enum called OGHRet which will be defined elsewhere.

Here's a fragment of code that shows enums and functions that return enums side by side...

```
enum Blah { Foo,  Bar };

enum Blah TellMeWhy()
{
   return Bar;
}
```

Comment: Seems reasonable, the enum type definition is located somewhere else, yet to be found.

Comment: It's saying that the type *has been* defined elsewhere.  References to incomplete enum types are not allowed in standard C (though some compilers may permit it as an extension).

Answer (score 1):

If you define an enum type like this:

```
enum OGHRet { foo, bar };
```

then `enum OGHRet` is simply the name of the type.  You can't refer to the type just as `OGHRet`; that's a tag, which is visible only after the `enum` keyword.

The only way to have a one-word name for the type is to use a typedef -- but it's really not necessary to do so.  If you insist on being able to call the type `OGHRet` rather than `enum OGHRet`, you can do this:

```
typedef enum { foo, bar } OGHRet;
```

Here the enumeration type is declared without a tag, and then the typedef creates an alias for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it isn't declared as a typedef, like this:

```
enum OGHRet
{
 FOO,
 BAR
};
```

Here you will need to make reference to this by `enum OGHRet`.
To use only `OGHRet`, you need to do it like this:

```
typedef enum _OGHRet
{
 FOO,
 BAR
}OGHRet;
```

Comment: Names beginning with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the implementation, it's better to not use them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `enum` keyword to provide a type definition for `OGHRet`. In C++, you can omit it.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742699/returning-an-enum-from-a-function-in-c), as well.