# Swift enum in objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, protocols

I have this enum in swift:

```
@objc enum HomeViewDataType: Int {
    case statistics
    case allTime
}
```

and this protocol;

```
@objc(TCHomeViewDataUpdaterDelegate)
protocol HomeViewDataUpdaterDelegate {
    ....
    func homeViewDataType() -> HomeViewDataType
}
```

If I ask Xcode to add the protocol stubs automatically it will add the `enum` keyword inside the return type parenthesis:

```
- (enum HomeViewDataType)homeViewDataType
{
    <code>
}
```

I never seen this before: `(enum HomeViewDataType)`

Any idea why?

It works with or without the `enum` keyword btw.

Comment: `enum HomeViewDataType` is a valid type notation in C/ObjC and you need to put the keyword `enum` to represent enum types unless you have some `typedef` of the enum. Better read the basic part of C-language.

Comment: thanks @OOPer. the bridging header generates the following:

typedef SWIFT_ENUM(NSInteger, HomeViewDataType) {
  HomeViewDataTypeStatistics = 0,
  HomeViewDataTypeAllTime = 1
};

When xcode generates the stub I assume it opts for adding the `enum` keyword even though it is not necessary.
ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/742716/429763

Comment: Yes, usually Apple's framework (in ObjC) uses `NS_ENUM` and it also generates `typedef`. I do not know why Swift does not use the shortest representation, but, just my guess, Swift team might want to use the same code base for no-typedef enums and typedef-ed enums.